# Basic math operations in a Jelly script

Tags: jenkins, jelly

So at work I have been tasked with the painful job of having to build an HTML email template for Jenkins using the Jenkins [Email Extension plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin). I've managed to get everything I needed for the template except for one piece. I need to calculate the passed percentage of the test run, but I can't find any way to run basic math operations in Jelly.

I've got the string values for 2 numbers (passed tests and total tests) and all I need to do is run (passed / total * 100) so I can get my percentage value. Is there any way to do this in Jelly?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do something like this:

```
${it.yourPassedVariable / it.yourTotalVariable}
```

As long as you reference your variables and do the calculation within the ${}, you should be good.